# NULL values loading file into mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, database, file

I have a file that contains a list of words and I am trying to load them into mysql table.
but what I get is only null values.

This is how my words are saved into the files

silver

gold

modern

paper

current

and so on

this is the related part of the code

```
String sqlkeywordcreate=new String ("CREATE TABLE keywordsTable " + " (k_id INTEGER       not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  keywords varchar(25))");
stmt1.executeUpdate(sqlkeywordcreate);

String sqlLoadkey ="load data local infile "      +"'E:/Thesis/ThesisWork/outdata/keywords.txt'"+ " \n" +   "   into table "+ "keywordsTable"+"lines terminated by '\r\n'";;
stmt1.executeUpdate(sqlLoadkey);
```

this is how the table is outputted

```
k_id | keywords

1    |  NULL

2    |  NULL
```

and so on.

I could not know what is wrong here specially that I have all the data no missing ones.
Help me please

Comment: you are reading from a file to a database?

Comment: yes, iam trying to load the data in the file into mysql table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your load command is essentially:

```
load data
    infile 'E:/Thesis/ThesisWork/outdata/keywords.txt'
    into table keywordsTable;
```

Your table has two columns.  So, it will try to put the string value into the first column.

To do what you want, try this:

```
load data
    local infile 'E:/Thesis/ThesisWork/outdata/keywords.txt'
    into table keywordsTable
    (keywords);
```